# Power set of $\mathbb{R}$ can't be countably generated?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there an easy argument to see that the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathbb{R}$ isn't  a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. there exist no $\{A_1,A_2,\dots\} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\sigma(\{A_1,A_2,\dots\})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123532/is-the-power-set-of-mathbb-r-a-countably-generated-sigma-algebra